# CSS3 animation behaves different in Firefox

Tags: html, css, animation, cross-browser

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danradic/BSVQv/4/).
I have searched a solution for this but didn't find one. 
 The correct one should be the one in Chrome/Opera/Safari. 
I want to show only the image from top to bottom.

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="image" src="http://www.hotel-aramis.com/slider/home/notre-dame-de-paris.jpg" />
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pan {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
100% {
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}
}
@keyframes pan {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
100% {
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -100%);
}
}

.container {
position:relative;
width:1100px;
height:480px;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#000;
}
.image {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
max-width:100%;
min-width:100%;
-webkit-animation: pan 5s alternate infinite linear;
animation: pan 5s alternate infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: You have both `@keyframes` and `@-webkit-keyframes` which is good, but both of them contain `-webkit-` prefixed `tranform` styles, which is probably a mistake. Obviously the unprefixed `@keyframes` should contain unprefixed `transform` styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox doesn't use webkit why your `-webkit-transform` will do nothing. Change it to `transform` and it should most likely work.

[I made a JSFiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/BSVQv/9/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes pan {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    }
    100% {
        top: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -100%);
    }
}
@keyframes pan {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0%, 0%);
    }
    100% {
        top: 100%;
        transform: translate(0%, -100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the browser supports `transform` then `@keyframes pan` will be triggered and the `-webkit` prefix is therefor not needed. You should however keep the prefix inside the `@-webkit-keyframes` block.

Comment: Any idea why the animation is so choppy?